# can't dismiss presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

i have two view controllers in iphone application.

1.) FirstVC

2.) SecondVC

In my FirstVC i have one button. By tapping on that button i opened SecondVC in `presentModalViewController`. look bellow code.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

now moved to SecondVC. On SecondVC i have create navigation bar as well as "cancel" button as a leftBarButtonItem. i set a button clicked event on cancel button. in that method i want to dismiss SecondVC. bellow method is in SecondVC. look bellow code.

```
- (void)cancelButtonClicked
{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This code dosen't work. i can't dismiss SecondVC by this code. Please suggest another tricks.

Comment: just remove navigationController when you try to present secondVC view... just try

Comment: @ParasJoshi : i tried also. but no luck.

Comment: First confirm that you are not dismissing it while some thread is running.

Comment: @ForamMukundShah : No. There is no thread is running.

Comment: ok. though I recommend you to write '[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(cancelButtonClicked) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
   '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the button code to this..

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
 [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

on cancelButtonClick

```
-(void)cancelButtonClicked {
 [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: i tried but when i clicked on `- (void)cancelButtonClicked` give me bad access error.

Comment: Have u used exactly the same..dismissed using self.parentViewController??

Comment: `- (void)cancelButtonClicked
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}` . This is what i tried.

Comment: Have u connected the cancel button to the target method..is it getting called properly??

Comment: and what is used to present..it should be [self presentModalViewController]..just wanted to make sure

Comment: `- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}`

Comment: tried updated answer. i don't know y it gives me bed access error every time.

Comment: ok..then the problem is definitely not this.it seems that any of your object  or variable in the firstVC is deallocated .try keeping breakPoints in viewWillAppear of firstVC  after clicking dismiss in secondVC

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18842/discussion-between-bhavin-p-and-appledelegate)

Comment: i have some internaly problem in my other code. but now it's working. i do it as bellow code
`- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}` and `- (void)cancelButtonClicked
{
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}`

Answer (score 3):

You are sending the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` message to the wrong object.

Since you presented the modal view controller through the navigation controller, then you should call:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will work on iOS 5 and newer. In case you are targeting only iOS 5 and newer, you could also think of using the newer methods that are available on it to manage modal view controllers:

```
– presentViewController:animated:completion:
– dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
```

but I don't think this is mandatory.

If you want to support iOS 4 and older, you should add a property to your modal view controller:

```
@interface SecondVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak/assign) UIViewController* presentingController;
...
@end
```

and set it before displaying the controller modally:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
     SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
     secondVC.presentingController = self.navigationController;
     [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

then you would use:

```
[self.presentingController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The second VC is just presented modally. It isn't a part of the navigation controller stack. Hence `self.navigationController` in second VC will evaluate to `nil`.

Comment: @Summer: You are perfectly right. I was too hasty. I changed my answer.

Comment: You are now sending the dismiss message to `presentingViewController` but using the old way of dismissing controllers.

Comment: Thank you again; I believe that would work all the same, but I have added a remark about the availability of the new methods under iOS>5.

Comment: Ideally the answer shouldn't be all this. The perfect solution is delegation. The presenting view controller will be delegate of the presented controller. And when cancel button is clicked on presented controller, it will delegate it to it's delegate, something like this - `[self.delegate secondControllerDidCancel:self]`. And then the presenting controller will implement that method and just send dismiss message on itself. This provides better encapsulation and communication. Just like how it works on Mail Composer, Camera, etc.

Comment: @Summer: you are right, the delegate approach is exactly what I used in my projects before iOS5... in fact, there are many possible designs...

Answer (score 0):

try this for present secondVC...

```
[self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace your code with the following... code

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    SecondVC *secondVC = [SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondVC" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}

- (void)cancelButtonClicked
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```